# Show that Sine is not in the span of Cosine

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that $\sin(x)$ is not in the span of $1$, $\cos(x)$, $\cos(2x)$, $\cos(3x)$, and $\cos(4x)$.

Can I do this without Taylor series?

Comment: Any functions in the span of $1$ and cosines are even functions but sine is odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One easy way to do this is to show that $\sin(x)$ is orthogonal to all of these functions with respect to the inner product
$$
\langle f,g \rangle = \int_0^{2 \pi} f(x) g(x)\,dx
$$
since non-zero, mutually-orthogonal vectors must also be linearly independent.

---

Alternatively, suppose that $f(x) = a_0 + a_1 \cos x + a_2 \cos(2x) + a_3 \cos(3x) + a_4 \cos(4x)$ is equal to $\sin(x)$.  Then we must have
$$
f(0) = 0\\
f(\pi/2) = 1\\
f(-\pi/2) = -1\\
$$
This gives us a system of equations on $a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ to which there is no solution.

Or, note that $f(x)$ must be even, whereas $\sin(x)$ is odd and non-zero.

Comment: How do I show this without calculus?

Comment: Glad to do it! Had a mistake in the second part before, see my edit. Also, achille's idea works equally well.